# How to find the SerialPort phisical address in Windows(7) on Kernel level

Tags: c++, driver

In the current project i am on, i have to read and write to a serial port directly on a Kernel level under Windows7 and above. Read/Write to the serial port shouldn't be different then Reading/Writing to an address in the memory. I was looking for few days on internet and i couldn't find enough information to get a clear picture on how it is done under windows. My idea is to write a driver[the driver is done] who will read and write to the serial port on Kernel level. The only thing is missing is the address. What i learn from my research is(may be I'm wrong): Windows make remap of all the IO devices on the system and each time assign different addresses. So for the COM1 (0x3F8 for BIOS) will be different address each time. Is there any Kernel level function(s) i will be able to find this address with.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not give you such direct access to any hardware device. To access a serial port you would open it like any other file or device and then use normal I/O functions (plus possibly ZwDeviceIoControl).

To find devices that offer a serial interface you would use CM_Get_Device_Interface_List with an InterfaceClassGuid  parameter of GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT.

Comment: I think this is what you mean: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/serial/VirtualSerial/device.h. But this is user mode. I really need kernel control.